# Turn around for or to something?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Once you tried out our product you won't ever turn around for/to XXX again!

(Where XXX is the competitors product.)

Can you even say that? If yes, which version is correct?

Comment: Be careful how you phrase it. Sentences like *"Once you [have] tried our food you won't try any others."* can be interpreted as *"Our food is so awful that it will kill you."*

Comment: It doesn't sound idiomatic or fluent to this US English speaker.  We don't say "turn around for/to a product".  It's more idiomatic to say you won't **turn to** or **turn back to** something, but the really idiomatic way to phrase it would be that you won't **go back** to something else.

Comment: I would write "Once you tried out our product you won't ever *turn to* XXX again!" You don't need *around* because it is included in the action of *turn*. And *to* because (figuratively) there are two items in this context, so you are facing one or turning to the other. Like in "point *to* this/that".

Answer (score 1):

Turn around for is more like, "I was going that way, but I turned around for some reason." Whereas, Turn around to is more like, "I was facing away from him, but then I turned around to see his face."

Turn around for - noun

Turn around to - verb

And while you can "turn around to a thing" it's not commonly said, and is 
awkward (you just "turn toward" instead). "I turned around to a new point of view." But in this sense it's more of a "facing towards" - It seems that these are adverbs in their role, because they answer the "why" question.

Unfortunately, this is bad copy anyway, and we lack context to make better sense out of the rest of the meaning that this sentence is trying to convey.

For example, "Try out our" is awkwardly phrased. But I digress.

EDIT: I would say, "Once you've tried our product, you won't want XXX again!" But even that is awkward. I'm sure there is better copy than that.

Comment: I don't think you digress at all. If my previous assumption that everything besides the decision between for/to is acceptable please tell me what to use instead.